# Options for: "with an average age of 12 (the youngest being 11 and the oldest, 14)."

Tags: grammar

While working on a translation, I came across this type of construction.

How do you construct/punctuate this?

> "with an average age of 12 (the youngest being 11 and the oldest, 14)."

This version is how I would actually say it, but is the punctuation be correct?

A couple of other options that might work:

> (youngest, 11; oldest, 14)
> (the youngest aged 11 and the oldest aged 14)

Are there any specific rules for this?

Comment: With an age range of 11 to 14, ...

Comment: Your first sentence is fine. But I would delete the comma.

Comment: Thank you, both responses much appreciated! In the end I am going with the simple "ranging from 11 to 14" (duh!) but the more complex construction will be useful for other instances where that's not appropriate, so thanks TonyK for the tip about the comma.